# how to send event when Collection is modified?

Tags: c#

Sorry I'm newbie in C# and events especially.
Why I receive NPE?

```
class WcfModel : IWcfModel
{
    private List<ConsoleData> _dataList;

    public List<ConsoleData> DataList
    {
        get { return _dataList; }
        set { _dataList = value;
            DataArrived(_dataList);  // NPE
        }
    }

    public event Action<List<ConsoleData>> DataArrived;
}
```

Comment: you need to initialze DataArrived variable

Comment: like that? `model.DataArrived += new Action<List<ConsoleData>>(model_DataArrived);` I do that but a little bit later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no object subscribed to the event (that is the delegate has no subscribers), it will be `null`. You need to test for that:

```
    set { 
        _dataList = value;

        var dataDel = DataArrived;
        if(dataDel != null)
            dataDel(_dataList);  
    }
```

Alternatively, use [`ObservableCollection<ConsoleData>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) - it has built in events for changes to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Rather use `ObservableCollection<ConsoleData>` which has its own **event publisher**.

```
class WcfModel : IWcfModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ConsoleData> _dataList;

    public WcfModel ()
    {
        _dataList = new ObservableCollection<ConsoleData>();
        _dataList.CollectionChanged += DataArrived

    }
    public ObservableCollection<ConsoleData> DataList
    {
        get { return _dataList; }
    }

    public event Action<object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> DataArrived;
}
```

Now whenever you do

```
wcfModelInstance.DataList.Add(new ConsoleData("hello"));
```

You will be notified when you subscribe `DataArrived` event in `WcfModel`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a null checker for the event as the following codes:

```
  class WcfModel: IWcfModel
  {
    private List<ConsoleData> _dataList;

    public List<ConsoleData> DataList
    {
      get { return _dataList; }
      set
      {
        _dataList = value;
        if ( DataArrived != null )
          DataArrived ( _dataList );
      }
    }

    public event Action<List<ConsoleData>> DataArrived;
  }
```